The sum of multiple non-i.i.d. beta prime variables
Suppose $X_1$,$X_2$,$X_3$ are i.i.d. gamma random variables, then $\frac{X_1}{X_2}$, $\frac{X_2}{X_3}$,$\frac{X_3}{X_1}$ are beta prime distributed and correlated with each other.
Then, what is the distribution for $\frac{X_1}{X_2}+\frac{X_2}{X_3}+\frac{X_3}{X_1}$?

Have you tried writing the joint density of $(X_1,X_2,Z)$ when $Z=\frac{X_1}{X_2}+\frac{X_2}{X_3}+\frac{X_3}{X_1}$ and integrating $X_1$ ans $X_2$ out?

For the gamma distribution with shape $\alpha=5,$ simulation gives something that looks like a shifted exponential distribution:
$$
\exp\left(-\frac32 (x-3)\right) \cdot \frac{3\,dx}2 \text{ for } x>3.
$$
I haven't yet figured out why that happens. If I do I may post some more.
Exercise: Prove that this random variable is never less than $3.$
y <- NULL
for(i in seq(20000)) {
x <- rgamma(3,5,1); u <- x[1]/x[2] + x[2]/x[3] + x[3]/x[1];
y <- c(y,u) }
y.sorted <- sort(y)
hist(y.sorted[seq(19000)], breaks = seq(30,55)/10, asp=1/2000)
lines(seq(300,550)/100, 2950 * exp(-1.5*(seq(0,250)/100)) )



One way to prove the sum of a positive number and its reciprocal is never less than $2$ is this:
$$
x + \frac1x = \left( \sqrt x - \frac1{\sqrt x} \right)^2 + 2.
$$
But showing $a/b + b/c + c/a \ge 3$ is what is needed in this problem.

The AM-GM inequality says for all positive $x,y,z,$ $$\frac{x+y+z}{3}\ge (xyz)^{1/3}.$$ With $x=a/b,$ $y=b/c,$ and $z=c/a,$ the right hand side is $1,$ qed. // The exponential is decent approximation to the distribution but only accidentally so: it's not the correct result.
